# indexOf on Javascript not working as expected on Array

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate through an Array to find the index of the highest numbers on it, then write those index numbers on another new Array.

I came up with this code:

```
let scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
let highestScore = Math.max(...scores);
let topScores = [];


for (score of scores) {
    if (score == highestScore) {
        topScores.push(scores.indexOf(score));
    }
}
console.log(topScores);
```

Then the result that the console shows is:

```
 topScores = [11, 11]
```

...when I expected:

```
 topScores = [11, 18]
```

as those are the positions where the highest numbers (both 69) are on the scores array.

Can someone explain to me what's happening? I searched but I can't come up with the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: `array.indexOf(x)` always returns the *first* position of `x` in the array. The first 69 is at index 11, regardless when and how you call indexOf.

Comment: change for loop to this
for (key in scores) {
    if (scores[key] == highestScore) {
        topScores.push(key);
    }
}

Comment: Simply add counter instead of `indexOf`

Comment: You can access the index in for..of as well, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by ***Fritz*** `Array.indexOf(x)` always returns the first position of x in the array. The first `69` is at index `11`.

You can use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of `for...of`:

```js
let scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
let highestScore = Math.max(...scores);
let topScores = [];


scores.forEach((score, index) => {
    if (score == highestScore) {
        topScores.push(index);
    }
})

console.log(topScores);
```

Comment: No need to change the type of loop. The index can be made available easily in `for .. of` as well, see my answer.

Comment: Sure, but that's less of a change than changing from `for..of` to `forEach`.

Comment: @connexo thanks to you as well and all the other people who took the time of answering! Learning a lot through your responses.

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause `indexOf` always return the first index at which element exist in array. You can use `reduce()`

```js
let scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
let highestScore = Math.max(...scores);
let res = scores.reduce((ac,a,i) => (a === highestScore && ac.push(i),ac),[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, both `indexOf` and `findIndex` always return the index of the first match. But there is no need for using either because you can access the current index in `for..of` like this:

```
for (const [index, score] of scores.entries())
```

which allows you to simply do

```
topScores.push(index);
```

```js
let scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
let highestScore = Math.max(...scores);
let topScores = [];


for (const [index, score] of scores.entries()) {
    if (score == highestScore) {
        topScores.push(index);
    }
}
console.log(topScores);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.indexOf()` returns only the index of the first occurrence of the particular ignore the other `indexes` so in this case, `indexOf` won't work. Just `loop` through and `push` the index of the value equal to the maximum number to a new `array`

```js
let scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

let noReplica = Math.max(...scores)
let ret = [];
for (let i = 0, length = scores.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] === noReplica) {
        ret.push(i)
    }
}

console.log(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

scores.indexOf(score) always returns the first position of score in the scores.

Use following code if you need the index.

```
for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i ++) {
    let score = scores[i];
    if (score == highestScore) {
        topScores.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(topScores);
```